# Unexpected results of boolean expressions in Python

Tags: python, python-2.x, operator-precedence

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does the expression 0 < 0 == 0 return False in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6074018/why-does-the-expression-0-0-0-return-false-in-python)

The following output from the Python 2 REPL confuses me:

```
>>> 15>10==True
False
>>> 15>1==True
True
>>> 15>2==True
False
>>> 15>False
True
```

If `15>10==True` is evaluated as `(15>10)==True` the expression would simplify to `print True==True`, which obviously evaluates to `True`. If `15>10==True` is evaluated as `15>(10==True)` the expression simplifies to `15>False` which also evaluates to `True`. Both of these interpretations contradict the actual value of the expression (`False`).

I can understand `15>1==True` evaluating to `True` since `1==True` is true, but no interpretation of `15>10==True` makes sense to me.

**Summary:** In Python 2, why does `15>10==True` evaluate to `False`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because [chained comparison](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in) in Python. Namely, `15>10==True` is actually evaluated as:

```
15 > 10 and 10 == True
```

which is `False`.

On the other hand, `15>1==True` is the same as

```
15 > 1 and 1 == True
```

which evaluates to `True`.

---

To quote from the docs:

> Unlike C, all comparison operations in Python have the same priority, which is lower than that of any arithmetic, shifting or bitwise operation. Also unlike C, expressions like a < b < c have the interpretation that is conventional in mathematics:

```
comparison    ::=  or_expr ( comp_operator or_expr )*
comp_operator ::=  "<" | ">" | "==" | ">=" | "<=" | "<>" | "!="
                   | "is" ["not"] | ["not"] "in"
```

> Comparisons yield boolean values: True or False.
>
> Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily, e.g., x < y <= z is equivalent to x < y and y <= z, except that y is evaluated only once (but in both cases z is not evaluated at all when x < y is found to be false).
>
> Formally, if a, b, c, ..., y, z are expressions and op1, op2, ..., opN are comparison operators, then a op1 b op2 c ... y opN z is equivalent to a op1 b and b op2 c and ... y opN z, except that each expression is evaluated at most once.
>
> Note that a op1 b op2 c doesn’t imply any kind of comparison between a and c, so that, e.g., x < y > z is perfectly legal (though perhaps not pretty).

Answer (score 2):

I beleive you're unknowingly running into a "neat" feature of python [operators](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#5.9):

> Unlike C, expressions like a < b < c have the interpretation that is conventional in mathematics:

```
In [12]: 15>10==True
Out[12]: False
```

True happens to be treated as 1 in this expression, ie:

```
In [13]: 15>10==1
Out[13]: False
```

But then replacing == with in a > operator, we see how the new expression is true as per the rule quoted above:

```
In [14]: 15>10>1
Out[14]: True
```