# What should be simple expression (containing less_than, is, and) result? Why?

Tags: python

Should be simple (tried both python 2 and python 3 under ubuntu 14.04)
Result seems a little puzzling to me.

So, here is the expression:

```
True is (True and 1) < 2
```

Comment: Don't do weird things, people will hate you.

Comment: You are asking Python to assert that both `True is (True and 1)` and `(True and 1) < 2` are true (operator chaining). `(True and 1)` is `1` (returning the `1` as both are true), so `True is (1)` is False, so the whole expression is False (`and` short-curcuits).

Comment: Those people will include yourself, later!

Comment: Now, after Martijn's comment it's totally clear that chaining has to be considered. And yes, it looks like a little more disguised version of question that's been already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6074018/why-does-the-expression-0-0-0-return-false-in-python