# Python: How to express less or equal, equal greater, environment?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to do the following example in python:

```
x = 10 
y = 8

if x-5 <= y <= x+5:
     print(y)
```

I see that this is working, but I would like to know if it's "ok" like this, if there is a better solution or something I have to consider doing it like this.

Comment: Yes, it's perfectly OK. Python is one of the few languages that allows this syntax.

Comment: Don't try it in C, Javascript, PHP, though....

Comment: See [the official documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#comparisons). `x-5 <= y <= x+5` is equivalent to `(x-5 <= y) and (y <= x+5)`, but less ugly.

Answer (score 0):

[Chained expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons) are acceptable in Python:

> Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily, e.g., `x < y <= z` is equivalent
>   to `x < y and y <= z`, except that `y` is evaluated only once (but in both
>   cases `z` is not evaluated at all when `x < y` is found to be `False`).

In fact, because `and` is lazy and the syntax is cleaner, they are *preferable*.

Just be aware that chained expressions take priority. For example, see [Why does the expression 0 < 0 == 0 return False in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6074018/why-does-the-expression-0-0-0-return-false-in-python).