# Python: how come False == False == True returns False?

Tags: python

please help to tell the basic logic of

```
>>>False == False == True
False
```

and the difference with (from the result, obviously the diff does have)

```
>>>(False == False) == True
True
```

Comment: The first one expands to `False == False and False == True`, it's chained

Comment: I believe we should use that duplicate instead: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6074018/5079316