# Why does [] == False evaluate to False but 0 == False to True in python?

Tags: python, boolean, equality

I am relatively new to Python and don't understand the following behavior:

Why does the statement

```
[] == False
```

evaluate to false, eventhough an empty list is falsy?

Here are more examples - in many other cases it seems that the empty list does behave in a falsy way, just not in [] == False...

```
>>> 0 == False                # what I'd expect
True
>>> not []                    # what I'd expect
True
>>> bool([])                  # what I'd expect
False
>>> [] == True                # what I'd expect
False
>>> [] == False               # unexpected
False
>>> bool([]) == False         # why does it evaluate to True again now?
True
>>> ([]) == (bool([]))        # unexpected
False
>>> (not []) == (not bool([]) # apparently adding 'not' makes it behave as expected again - why?
True
```

Can somebody please explain this to me? How are these statements internally evaluted? 
I have a feeling it might be related to chaining comparisons ([see e.g. here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6074018/why-does-the-expression-0-0-0-return-false-in-python)), but cannot really understand if that's correct and why.

Comment: False and falsey are not the same thing

Answer (score 2):

Because falsy isn't `False`. Falsy just means

```
bool(some_object) is False
```

So,

```
>>> bool([]) is False
True
>>> bool({}) is False
True
>>> bool(0) is False
True
```

Comment: OK, so what is the difference in this respect between 0 and an empty list? Is it correct to say, that 0 is both falsy and False, whereas an empty list is only falsy but not False?

Comment: @sam_sc because in Python, due to historical reasons, booleans are subclasses of `int` with exactly two values, True and False, that are equal to 1 and 0 respectively.

Comment: @sam_sc sure, that's a reasonable thing to say.

Comment: OK, that historical explanation makes sense to me. I had a feeling it's something like that. Thanks for your answer, this helps a lot!