# Is there a use for == or != in chained comparisons?

Tags: python, comparison-operators

I came across this question:

[Why does the expression 0 < 0 == 0 return False in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6074018/5987)

The answers make perfect sense once you understand chained comparisons in Python.

Chained comparisons allow you to write something like `0 < x < 100` which is very convenient for testing to see if something is between 0 and 100. But is there a case where it would even make sense to use `==` or `!=` on either side of that comparison? `0 < x == 100` is equivalent to `x == 100` for example.

Were `==` and `!=` included in the chaining syntax just so that they wouldn't have to be exceptions to the rule, or is there an actual use case?

Comment: `x == y == z` is pretty clearly useful. (The one that causes the most problems is `in`.)

Comment: @user2357112 You should submit that as an answer, it makes perfect sense.

Comment: Taking into account that all of the operators can be reimplemented and modified in behaviour there are virtually endless use-case for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most common use case for chaining `==` is chaining it with itself. `x == y == z` is a simple way to test that three things are all equal.

Using `!=` in a comparison chain is also occasionally useful, but it tends to be less clear. `0 < x != 10` is more concise than `0 < x and x != 10`, but the two comparisons don't feel quite as much like one big comparison as `x == y == z` does, and `x != y != z` is usually a mistake.